# Moving boxes between warehouses: memory allocation issues

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array

**THE TASK**

There are **M** warehouses (M <= 100000) with wares of certain weights arranged inside. First, we are given M lines of input where each line looks like this:

t a1 a2 a3 a4...

where **t** is the number of arranged items inside the warehouse and a1 a2 a3 a4... are their weights (t <= 1000000, weight <= 2147483647)

We are then given **Q** inquiries (Q <= 200000) of two types:

**K** - print out the total weight of all wares inside each warehouse

**R** mz md tp tk - Move all wares with indexes between (and including) **tp** and **tk** from the warehouse that has the index number **mz** to the **end of the warehouse** that has the index **md**.

mz,md <= 100000

-255 <= tp,tk <= 255

**Indexes start from 1** (Index 1 - first item, Index 2 - second item, etc.).
Negative index -n means that I want an item with index n counting from the end (so -1 will be the last item in the warehouse).

Basically, if I have two warehouses with items (their weights) arranged like so

**1.** 2 3 4

**2.** 5 12 1

And then I input:

R 2 1 1 -1

K

I'm going to move all the items from warehouse 2 to the end of warehouse 1 (preserving their order) so that it looks like so:

**1.** 2 3 4 5 12 1

**2.**

And then print out the sums of both like so:

27 0

**EXAMPLES**

**A** Input:

1 1

1 1

K

Output:

1

**B** Input:

3 5

2 1 1

0

4 1 2 3 4

K

R 3 2 1 -1

K

R 2 1 1 1

K

Output:

2 0 10

2 10 0

3 9 0

**C** Input:

2 6

3 2 2 2

2 3 3

K

R 1 2 2 -2

K

R 1 2 1 -1

R 2 1 1 -1

K

Output:

6 6

4 8

12 0

**MY CODE**

I've written some basic foundations of what I would like the finished program to look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {

    long int M,Q,t,ware;
    if (scanf("%ld %ld",&M,&Q) != 2)
    {
        printf("Invalid Input");
    }
    char check;
    //declaration of warehouse size - subject to change
    long int warehouses[M+1][1000];
    //array with sums of weights of items in each warehouse
    long long int sumy[M+1];
    //array with sizes of each warehouse
    long int length[M+1];
    for (int i = 1; i<M+1;i++)
    {
        if (scanf(" %ld",&t) != 1)
        {
            printf("Invalid Input");
        }
        length[i] = t;
        for (int j = 1; j<t+1;j++)
        {
            if (scanf(" %ld",&ware) != 1)
            {
                printf("Invalid Input");
            }
            warehouses[i][j] = ware;
            sumy[i] += ware;
        }
    }
    long int mz,md;
    int tp,tk;
    for (int k = 0;k<Q;k++)
    {
        if (scanf(" %c",&check) != 1)
        {
            printf("Invalid Input");
        }
        if (check == 'K')
        {
            for (int ki = 0; ki < M;ki++)
            {
                printf("%lld",sumy[ki+1]);
                printf(" ");
            }
             printf("\n");
        }else
        {
            //indexes of "from warehouse" and "to warehouse"
            if (scanf(" %ld %ld",&mz,&md) != 2)
            {
                printf("Invalid Input");
            }
            //indexes of the range of items we want to transport
             if (scanf(" %d %d",&tp,&tk) != 2)
             {
                 printf("Invalid Input");
             }
            if (tp < 0)
            {
                tp = length[mz] + tp + 1;
            }
            if (tk < 0)
            {
                tk = length[mz] + tk + 1;
            }
            for (int kj = 0; kj <= tk - tp ;kj++)
            {
                //moving items - subject to change
                warehouses[md][length[md]+1] = warehouses[mz][tp + kj];
                sumy[mz] -= warehouses[mz][tp + kj];
                sumy[md] += warehouses[mz][tp + kj];
                warehouses[mz][tp + kj] = 0;
                length[md] += 1;
                length[mz] -= 1;

            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

A glaring issue would be declaring the 2D array like so `long int warehouses[M+1][1000];` (inefficient memory management + I can't make this as big as it was supposed to be because it'd require too much memory) instead of doing it dynamically but this is precisely why I made this thread. I'm somewhat new to C programming and using memory allocation and pointers still seems quite difficult to me. Ideally, I would like this code to have a "dynamic 2D array" (using an array of pointers comes to mind but maybe someone has a better idea) and then reallocate the size based on the transportation of wares. If someone could rewrite those parts and help me understand how they work I'd be very grateful. Suggestions are welcome too.

Comment: Please get into the habit of using array indexes as *zero* based. If you continue to use one-based array indexes you will be very lonely, and few experienced programmers would want to work with your code.

Comment: Were you taught about linked lists in this course? About doubly-linked lists?

Comment: As a note you can just type `long` instead of `long int`, makes the code a little less verbose. I'd also recommend you look into `stdint.h` and just always using `int64_t` or `uint64_t`; that way you don't need to worry about platform-specific `long` vs `long long` junk

Comment: The fact, that the size of each warehouse is subject to change and that you may need to slice out items from the middle of a warehouse (ie when you move items between the warehouses) suggests that arrays are not the best concept for this type of task. Because both of these operations are very expensive with arrays. I'd consider @EricPostpischil suggestion to go with linked lists. On the other hand, those linked lists, don't allow you to easily access specific elements by index.

Comment: You may want to use range trees in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Adjusted using linked lists:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int weight;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

typedef struct {
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
} Warehouse;

Warehouse warehouses[100001];

void insertItem(int mz, int weight) {
    Node *newNode = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->weight = weight;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if (warehouses[mz].head == NULL) {
        warehouses[mz].head = warehouses[mz].tail = newNode;
    } else {
        warehouses[mz].tail->next = newNode;
        warehouses[mz].tail = newNode;
    }
}
void adjustNegativeIndex(int mz, int *tp, int *tk, int length[]) {
    if (*tp < 0) {
        *tp = length[mz] + *tp + 1;
    }
    if (*tk < 0) {
        *tk = length[mz] + *tk + 1;
    }
}

void moveItems(int mz, int md, int tp, int tk) {
    Node *start = warehouses[mz].head;
    Node *prev = NULL;
    int count = 1;
    while (count < tp && start != NULL) {
        prev = start;
        start = start->next;
        count++;
    }

    Node *end = start;
    count = tp;
    while (count < tk && end != NULL) {
        end = end->next;
        count++;
    }

    if (start == NULL || end == NULL) return;

    if (prev == NULL) {
        warehouses[mz].head = end->next;
    } else {
        prev->next = end->next;
    }

    if (warehouses[md].head == NULL) {
        warehouses[md].head = start;
    } else {
        warehouses[md].tail->next = start;
    }

    warehouses[md].tail = end;
    end->next = NULL;
}
void printTotalWeights(int m) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
        int sum = 0;
        Node *curr = warehouses[i].head;
        while (curr != NULL) {
            sum += curr->weight;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        printf("%d ", sum);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    int m, q;
    if (scanf("%d %d", &m,&q) != 2)
    {
        printf("Invalid Input");
        return 0;
    }
    int length[m+1];

    for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
        int t, weight;
        if (scanf(" %d", &t) != 1)
        {
            printf("Invalid Input");
            return 0;
        }
        length[i] = t;
        for (int j = 0; j < t; j++) {
            if (scanf(" %d", &weight) != 1)
            {
                printf("Invalid Input");
                return 0;
            }
            insertItem(i, weight);
        }
    }
    while (q--) {
        char op;
        if (scanf(" %c", &op) != 1) {
            printf("Invalid Input");
            return 0;
        }

        if (op == 'K') {
            printTotalWeights(m);
        } else {
            int mz, md, tp, tk;
            if (scanf("%d %d %d %d", &mz, &md, &tp, &tk) != 4) {
                printf("Invalid Input");
                return 0;
            }
            adjustNegativeIndex(mz, &tp, &tk, length);
            moveItems(mz, md, tp, tk);
            length[mz] -= tk-tp+1;
            length[md] += tk-tp+1;
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is this? Code that works? Or just code using linked lists that you still have questions about? Is it supposed to be an answer to the question? Code without explanation is not a good answer.